# The joy of MVVM and IoC

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control

I'm putting together an application to help manage the repairs we process here at work. I've been instructed to go down the WPF route. Brief into to the scenerio is; I would say the data structure is fairly simple, but its the changing business processes that make it more complex. Like any repair as you would expect there is an RMA form filled in by a customer, in this system this becomes an RMA object that contains a lengthy list of properties to record customer entered details and then details entered by the engineers during the repair until its dispatched. Data storage is a database on a webserver protected by OAuth. Course APIs to retrieve data (i.e. all

I am fine with XAML to create the WPF which was the first hurdle, and some knowledge of ViewModel/View interaction using Commands + data binding. I am more stuck on the architecture at this point. Firstly people do the creation/linking of View/ViewModel differently. Also from my research IoC is the way to go, but every tutorial I read does it in a different way using a variety of IoC frameworks (i.e. Unity/Spring). And its at this point I have gotten lost amongest the terminology and the variety was ways to achieve the same thing.

[image: Preview of repair system]

Above is a screenshot of how the application will end up looking. Originally created in photoshop by our web designer and I turned it into xaml. Obviously the tab control showing Summary/JobSheet isn't finished :)

As you can see the application has 3 main areas.

1) The header with a search box,

2) A list of buttons down the side which vary based on a users role (these act much like filters in GMail, show all pending repairs, starred repairs etc), the tabbed view in the middle.

3) The tabbed view has a main tab (based on the button clicked down the side), and other tabs i.e. an open RMA, Customer, etc. The idea of the application is you scan a barcode on an RMA form, that data (number) is put into the search box, which queries the web services through a repository (gets the RMA data as a Json string, builds the RMA object from Json), creates a ViewModel for it and displays it as a tab.

I've looked through a few tutorials already, but as I say they all differ and am not sure on the approach to take, such as.

Naked mvvm - http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2010/11/07/naked-mvvm-simplest-possible-mvvm-approach.aspx#comments

John Smith - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Mvvm in the box - http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/

**Question**
With this in mind can anyone advise on the best architecture to use in this application. The side buttons hint at a type of modular design, however the header, main tab control, showing RMA details are core to the system.
Can you provide examples/url's to suitable tutorials to build a sample application on before continuing to implement it on this project.

Comment: It's a big question about app design in general and I'm not sure how much detail you are expecting.  There is nothing special or that needs extra consideration in your app.  You could use MVVM, you could use IoC, but you don't have to.  It sounds like you're not super-familiar with app design as a whole.  *Any* app that's well designed will be written with change and modularity in mind.  Invoking frameworks to handle things like IoC are good, but you should first understand how IoC works and why it's good.  Simply deciding that you need to use framework X at this point jumps the gun.

Comment: It's pretty easy to start with roll your own MVVM, and bring in MVVM-Light or something as needed. IoC approaches are nice, but you might be biting off too much to chew for your first WPF app.

Comment: As a fresh graduate from university, I have some knowledge with design but not at the GUI end, other than MVC/MVP. WPF and MVVM work well together, and almost very tutorial I read moves to IoC as the way to go to avoid dependencies and hook up the view and ViewModel. I agree when loads of terminology is added I do not understand, I have to take a step back which is what I am trying to do now. I will look at the MVVM-light framework.

Comment: I've looked around MVVM-light and found it to be lacking in WPF samples and documentation. In looking for samples I came across Simple MVVM framework, but this seems to have a silverlight preference and reverts back to using events rather than commands which seem more applicable to WPF. I think the pure MVVM explanation provided by John Smith is more suitable to me.

Comment: To better get your head around MVVM, check the Rockford Lhotka videos, Rob Eisenbergs "Build Your Own MVVM Framework", and the Caliburn Micro framework - those combined gave me the "aha!" moment.

Comment: Ill watch them at home, plus the "Jason Dolinger MVVM". As I have no speakers at work. The aha moment is what I'm after, in learning WPF and WVP I had many of them along the way. I find mvvm more complex when your looking to customise, i.e. you have an RMAView, thus the RMAViewModel behind it needs to have a rma number set to it some where so it loads the correct one from the webserver. Where is it set, and what has a reference to the ViewModel if its created via IoC. How do two ViewModels talk to each other, and how do you handle nesting of view/viewmodel. These are all topics i aim to cover

Comment: Ugh.  I kinda hate doing it, seeing as you put so much effort into the question....

Comment: @Will, Sigh, I was hoping to have been pointed in a direction in order to continue development, but i understand why it was closed. I'll continue reading material around MVVM but avoid frameworks and IoC still for the time being to avoid complications. I thought frameworks were meant to help simplify and speed up development, yet for me it has the opposite effect.

Comment: @JonWillis: Well, if it gets reopened I won't close again.  Questions like this are hard; they are very localized and end up being useless within the year, but *so* many people are interested in asking them.  Hell, I've closed a number of questions of this type that I asked back during the early days of SO.  You might try asking in a relevant chat room, but I'd rate the success of that as low.  Another option is to plea your case on [meta], but that's been done and failed several times.  Personally, I'm with you on MVVM frameworks.  Haven't found one that is high speed/low drag.

Comment: @Will, Cheers for the detailed response will. As i said I understand the reasons for closing questions as its very specific to a problem.